# How to upgrade Intellij to 2017 on Linux?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to upgrade Intellij from 2016.3 to 2017.1. This is a major upgrade, so it is not doable simply by clicking "Upgrade", I have to download a whole new tar.gz. The problem is that I don't want to do a fresh installation, because I have some plugins and configuration I would rather not loose. How can I do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Install as you normally do for the new version (unpack into the new empty directory, then run via `bin/idea.sh`), it will suggest to import the settings from the previous version the first time you start it.

To automate updates you may consider using [JetBrains Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/).

Comment: For those who came from Eclipse world on Window, couple of useful links https://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-open-a-tar-file-in-unix-or-linux/ , https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files